# Tag proposal for puzzles that require computer literacy

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

In a [recent comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/11009/40#comment33521_11019), [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373) suggested creating a tag for puzzles that are difficult to solve without some level of computer literacy. I think this is a good idea.

Here's my proposal for a new [programming](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag to cover questions like these. Let me know what you think.

---

> **Programming:** A puzzle that may be difficult or even impossible to solve without some degree of computer literacy.

Comment: We might alternatively redirect some such puzzles to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Joffan, only if you want them to be closed.

Comment: @PeterTaylor or migrated, yes. I'm not saying that every such puzzle would have this outcome; only that it is  probably suitable for some puzzles. And in fact I support the tag proposal.

Comment: +1 from me (naturally!) But involving some degree of computer literacy isn't necessarily the same as requiring knowledge of *programming* - e.g. it could be related to ASCII codes or suchlike. Maybe the tag could be called something like [computer-knowledge]? I know that doesn't sound very good; can anyone improve it?

Comment: Perhaps pacoverflow has done the job for us with [the computer-puzzle tag](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle) created 8 hours ago?

Answer (score 8):

I didn't see this question until just now.  I think the [computer-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle) tag would be perfect for questions that require computer literacy.

I agree with rand al'thor's comment that a [programming](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag wouldn't cover puzzles that require computer literacy but don't involve programming at all.

Comment: I've gone ahead and synonymized [tag:programming] into [tag:computer-puzzle] and written a short tag wiki for [tag:computer-puzzle].

Comment: @Emrakul It seems the programming tag is synonymous with the computer-literacy tag, not the computer-puzzle tag.  Was that a mistake?

Comment: Er... oops. >_>